# Method Replication in Postgresql 9.5

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Hy guys . help me. 
What is Difference wal level logical, hot_standby, minimal, logical and what is wal segment whether need to use big segment or not?

now i use Wal_segment : 50. 
why after I try insert 5 million row segment archive over 50?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter `wal_level` determines how much information is written to the transaction log (*write-ahead log*, short *WAL*).

The settings in decreasing order of amount of WAL emitted:

- For logical replication or logical decoding, you need `logical`.
- To run physical replication with hot standby, you need `hot_standby`.
- To archive WAL files with `archive_mode = on`, you need `archive`.
- The `minimal` level logs only the information required for crash recovery.

Note that from PostgreSQL 9.6 on, `archive` and `hot_standby` have been deprecated and replaced with the new setting `replica`.

A *WAL segment* is one 16 MB transaction log file as seen in `pg_xlog` or `pg_wal`.

I guess that with `wal_segment` you mean the parameter `checkpoint_segments` (`max_wal_size` since 9.5).

It does not pose an absolute limit on the number of WAL segments, it determines after how much WAL a checkpoint will be forced. If your `archive_command` is slow, WAL may pile up.